# spark 1.6 hive context setConf Issue

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hivecontext

I am having trouble to run a sql which loads data to partition table  in hive context , I did set `dynamic partition = true` but still I am having issue.

---

SQL:

`insert overwrite table target_table PARTITION (column1,column2) select * , deletion_flag  ,'2018-12-23' as date_feed from source_table`

---

Hive setconf:-

```
  hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true")
  hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions","2048")
  hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```

---

Error:

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, boolean, int, boolean, boolean, boolean

---

Maven Dependency:-

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: post the error message, cause and some of stack trace.

Comment: That looks a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46124389/1305344 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/40637607/1305344, but unfortunately either does not offer an accepted answer.

Comment: please check this link for stack trace error, http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Hive-loadDynamicPartitions-Issue/m-p/63034#M3128

Comment: tried this but no luck (http://dmlcoding.com/2017/SparkBug/)

Comment: solved:- after getting all the maven depdencies from cloudera repos

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issues after getting all the maven dependencies from cloudera repo.

```
 <dependencies>
    <!-- Scala and Spark dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-cdh5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAP4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-xml_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.172</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scopt</groupId>
        <artifactId>scopt_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-hadoop</id>
        <name>Hadoop Releases</name>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera-repos</id>
        <name>Cloudera Repos</name>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```